# Can we replace one variable with multiple variables using sed

Tags: linux, bash

I have a config file where i need to replace the entire line with new values. It can be either a word or a URL. I am trying to write a script to replace only this particular parameter with new values.

I have tried using `grep` to extract the line using the parameter and divided the values separately and saved in two different variables.
Now I am trying to replace the whole line with the parameter along with new value or url usind `sed`

```
jaram=`grep -i "$a" app.properties`;
param=`grep -i "$a" app.properties |sed 's/\'$a'=*//'`;

sed -e 's~'$jaram'~'$a=''$changed_param'~g' app.properties
```

The config file contains:

```
abc1=http://howareyou:scema=olk
abc2=http://howareyou:scema=olk
```

Here I am trying to replace the url of only `abc1`. though both have same value. I need to replace the entire url with something different url or a word.

Here I am trying to find the line which contains `abc1` and this line url after `=` is saved in a different variable.

I tried to replace the url with new one using sed:

```
sed -i 's~'$jaram'~'$a=''$param'~g' app.properties
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Seems like I am doing wrong at some syntax when using `sed`

trying to replace something like

```
sed 's/jaram/'{$a=$param}/'
```

Expecting an output like

```
abc1=http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj
abc2=http://howareyou:scema=olk
```

Comment: `sed 's/^\('"$a"'=\).*/\1'"$changed_param"'/' file`?

Comment: oguz, $a is my input for the parameter, this would be either abc1 or abc2, based on this my values get divided and combined with new values for the same $a value. the one that you gave, did not help here

Comment: @SivaMalla, I am getting a bit confused with your question. You should prefer showing how you expect the output to look. In your question you have combined your `sed` command and other things together in a yellow block and it got really had to figure out what output you want.

Comment: Are `jaram` and `param` variables relevant? If so what do they contain? Which value you want to substitute? The `http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj` string is stored inside `$a`?

Comment: yes , jaram contains abc1=http://howareyou:scema=olk and param contains http://howareyou:scema=olk
and $a contains abc1

Comment: I don't understand why the `sed` expression by @oguzismail did not work. What output did it give you? I ask because that would be my approach as well: search for the parameter you want, `abc1`, followed by `=` and the rest of the line, and change the rest of the line to the new value. This approach should work in general, and might just need some tweaking for your specific case.

Comment: Where does the `http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj` come from? Doesn't `param=http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj`?

Comment: In fact, I just test the `sed` command given by @oguzismail, first setting `a=abc1` and `changed_param='http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj'`, and it almost worked: the only issue was that I have to change `/` to `~` since you have instances of `/` in the replacement string.

Comment: http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj would be my new input to update in abc1

Comment: So this worked for me: `sed -i 's~^\('"$a"'=\).*~\1'"$changed_param"'~' app.properties`

Comment: thanks Joanis, the one that you gave me worked like a charm...seems like I did my mistake at the syntax, thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script with comments:

```
# recrete the input config file
cat <<EOF >input
abc1=http://howareyou:scema=olk
abc2=http://howareyou:scema=olk
EOF

# some input variables
name="abc1"
newvalue='http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj'

# the sed script
sed -i 's'$'\01''^'"$name"'=.*'$'\01'"$name"'='"$newvalue"$'\x01' input

# and the output
cat input
```

produces the following output:

```
abc1=http://jalkek:kj/iuwerj
abc2=http://howareyou:scema=olk
```

Notes:

- I used the `0x01` byte as the separator for `s` command inside `sed`. So it should work with all printable characters.
- Remember about quoting. All variables should be inside `"` double quotes, but all the rest would be best if inside `'` single quotes.
- I match the name= with `^`, so from the beginning of the line. So that for example `blablaabc1=` doesn't match.
- I use [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) from bash to generate the unredable `0x01` bytes to delimit sed command.

A little more readable version of the sed script could be this one, that just uses `"` for quoting and uses `~` as a separator:

```
 sed "s~^${name}=.*~${name}=${newvalue}~"
```

Comment: Given the core `sed` command of your solution came from @oguzismail 's comment, I would have made this answer a community wiki, although you did add a lot more research and details, so I guess it's not a clear cut case...